# Changing G+ url parameter without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, google-plus

I have a link that a user can share on `fb` and `G+`.

The user can modify that link and he did it with an ajax call so the page is not refreshing.

My gplus button code  :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ url }}" />
<g:plus action="share" style="height: 28px;" ></g:plus>
```

when the user changes the url I update the `href` attribute too :

```
$.post(url,{
       someParams:"someValues"
   },function(data){
 .
 .
 .
 // updating the href attribute with the new modified url 
 $('link[rel="canonical"]').attr("href",data.url);
 }
```

The problem is that the `G+` button still load the old url.
But only by refreshing I get the new one.

My question is how can i change the `G+` url without refreshing the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want (obviously changing that prompt for your ajax callback logic)?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/2783J/6/

**HTML**

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
<div id="gplus"></div>
<button>change it!</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    var container = $('#gplus');
    var render = function(url) {

        container.html('<g:plusone href="' + url + '"></g:plusone>');
        gapi.plusone.go('gplus');

    };

    $('button').click(function(event){

        var url = prompt('Give me an URL');
        render(url);

    });

    render(location.href);

});
```

Be aware that I'm loading the plusone.js in the external resources of that jsfiddle.

BTW, why did you use the Symfony2 tag?

Comment: `gapi.plusone.go('gplus')` that's what i wass missing !
Symfony2 tage is because `{{url}}` is a twig tag that renders the url variable

Comment: Ah ok! nice!. Those Google API's get tricky sometimes. If you think this is the right answer then please, set it as accepted!